# Confusion over .NET 4 Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await

I am using the Microsoft.Bcl.Async nuget package to use Async/Await (My target is .NET 4, rather than 4.5)

I am new to Async/Await. My problem is described in the following code sample. Why is the highlighted line not called?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();

        Console.WriteLine("Got the value");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Async...");

        var val = await AsyncMethod();

        // HIGHLIGHTED LINE. WHY IS THIS LINE NOT CALLED?
        Console.WriteLine("And the value is... {0}", val);
    }

    public static Task<long> AsyncMethod()
    {
        long myVal = 1;

        for (long l = 0; l < 100000; l++)
        {
            myVal++;
            Console.WriteLine("l = {0}", l);
        }

        return new Task<long>(() => myVal);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not the reason but you need to put for loop in to task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
Console.WriteLine("And the value is... {0}", val);
```

is converted (by the compiler) into a *continuation*; it will get invoked (with the value etc) only when the task that is being "awaited" completes. The problem is: you *create* a task, but you haven't *started* it: so it will never complete.

If you *start* the task you create at the bottom, it will eventually complete. Also, normally you would put the "doing" work *inside* the `Task` - not outside it:

```
    public static Task<long> AsyncMethod()
    {
        var task = new Task<long>(() =>
        {
            long myVal = 1;

            for (long l = 0; l < 100000; l++)
            {
                myVal++;
                Console.WriteLine("l = {0}", l);
            }
            return myVal;
        });
        task.Start();
        return task;
    }
```

Also note that `Got the value` gets printed out **long before** the `And the value is...` - that is because the *continuation* happens **on a worker thread**; the `Run` method returns control to the caller (`Main`) at the first `await`.

Comment: Any reason you didn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Run`?

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't call it "AsyncMethod" because it have no async elements.

The method uses a Task that will run in a separate thread from Current thread.